# Узнать относительный адрес внутри проекции PE-файла

Tags: c++, winapi, pe

Есть один известный крэкми. После его изучения оказывается, что для его взлома достаточно пропатчить два байта по адресу `40138B` (забить условный переход NOP'ами) и два байта по адресу `401243` (прописать там безусловный переход). Я хочу написать программу, которая делает это автоматически.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

enum {OK, CANT_OPEN};

int patch (TCHAR* fname)
{
    char first_patch[2]  = {0x90, 0x90};    // NOP NOP
    char second_patch[2] = {0xEB, 0x07};    // JMP 40124C
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(fname,
                              FILE_ALL_ACCESS, NULL,
                              NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                              FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return CANT_OPEN;

    int SizeFile  = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    HANDLE MhFile = CreateFileMapping(hFile, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, SizeFile, 0);
    HANDLE View   = MapViewOfFile(MhFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);

    UnmapViewOfFile(View);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    CloseHandle(MhFile);
    return OK;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TCHAR* default_fname = "CRACKME.EXE";

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        default_fname = argv[1];
    }

    patch(default_fname);

    std::cout << default_fname << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Я спроецировал исполняемый файл в адресное пространство процесса и получил адрес этой проекции. Теперь надо пропатчить этот образ, после чего процедура `UnmapViewOfFile` сохранит изменения на диск.

Как в этой проекции найти адреса типа `40138B` и `401243`? Где можно посмотреть теорию и примеры по редактированию PE-файлов?

Далее пишу **хрень**, можно не читать.
Успешно напечатал сигнатуру `MZ`, это значит, что при помощи `View` можно заполнять структуры заголовков, используя, возможно, для выравнивания макросы Криса Касперски.

```
char M = *((char *) View);
char Z = *((char *) View + 1);
std::cout << M << Z << std::endl;
```

Проверка того, что заголовок дос успешно загружен. Потом добавлю код для отлавливания возможных ошибок.

```
unsigned myRVAtoRAW(HANDLE pe_image, unsigned rva)
{
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos_header;
    std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dos_header), pe_image, sizeof(dos_header));

    std::cout << (dos_header.e_magic == 'ZM') << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Изучаете формат MZPE-заголовков, в особенности таблицы секций. Потом пишете трансляцию RVA (а даже не VA как у вас) в физическое смещение.

Answer (score 3):

Можно пойти двумя путями:

1. Разобраться и написать самому. Тогда рекомендую почитать статью: [Разработка функций RvaToRaw и RawToRva](https://habrahabr.ru/post/129241/).
2. Либо воспользоваться функций из известной `dbghelp.dll`.

Я бы посоветовал разобраться, благо это не сложно. Также следует отметить знаменитую статью [Об упаковщиках в последний раз: Часть первая - теоретическая](http://uinc.ru/articles/41/)

Comment: О, хорошие статьи, спасибо.

Comment: Для получения ImageBase я ведь могу воспользоваться указателем, который вернула MapViewOfFile и заполнить структуры заголовков?

Comment: `ImageBase` это значение, которое задается в заголовке. Это ничто иное как гипотеза, которую выдвинул компилятор относительно адреса загрузки исполняемого файла. Компилятору же надо как-то строить код использующий адреса! От чего-то же надо отталкиваться. Вот это "что-то" и есть `ImageBase`. А вот по факту может оказаться так, что системный загрузчик загрузил по другому адресу и вот тогда вступает в силуа таблица перемещаемых элементов.

Comment: А еще я не понимаю вот что. Если абсолютный адрес в оперативке складывается из относительного адреса и адреса загрузки, то почему адрес загрузки может быть одинаковым? Память в винде представляет собой один большой сегмент, но программы должны размещаться в нем по разным адресам. Почему может быть загружено несколько программ с адресом загрузки 400000? Еще в статье пишут, что этот адрес может меняться загрузчиком.

Comment: Понятно, в HIEW виден один адрес, но при загрузке он может меняться, поэтому ImageBase надо доставать из поля структуры после загрузки. Верно?

Comment: Читайте статьи, там все есть!

Comment: В статье об упаковщиках опечаток нет? Говорится о том, что SizeOfRawData должно быть меньше поля VirtualSize, как иллюстрация приводится скрин Hiew, где это условие выполняется, и далее: вот поэтому и появляются знаки вопроса... как будто на этой картинке показали некорректные значения, хотя условие "меньше" там выполнено. Или это я не понимаю?

Comment: Welcome to PE32 format! :) Нет, я серьезно. Этот формат далеко не прост как кажется :)

Answer (score 1):

Что касаемо патчинга:

```
int main() {

  HWND hWnd = FindWindow(0, "Calculator");

  if(hWnd == 0){

    MessageBox(0, "Error cannot find window.", "Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);

  } else {

    DWORD proccess_ID;

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &proccess_ID);

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, proccess_ID);

    if(!hProcess){

      MessageBox(0, "Could not open the process!", "Error!", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);

    } else {

      DWORD newdatasize = sizeof(newdata);

      if(WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)0x40138B , "0x90", newdatasize, NULL)){

        MessageBox(NULL, "WriteProcessMemory worked.", "Success", MB_OK + MB_ICONINFORMATION);

      } else {

        MessageBox(NULL, "Error cannot WriteProcessMemory!", "Error", MB_OK + MB_ICONERROR);

      }

      CloseHandle(hProcess);

    }

  }

  return 0;

}
```

Адреса искать по паттерну(уникальной сигнатуре), сделать ее можно в любом отладчике